# How we update UITableView on Row Did Select?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am using a Table View, I want when the user click on the row Table reload itself and show the new data on the same Table.

Comment: Did you try [self.tableView reloadData] in the tableViewControllers didSelectCell method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what a user would suspect to happen, why not use an `UINavigationController` and push a new `UIViewController` on the stack with the new data.

Comment: It's a good option but i want to use only one UIViewController in the application.

Comment: You could still use one `UIViewController` just another instance of it on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

[self.tableView reloadData];

this code is you want it?